# Rails npm run watching npm ERR! Missing script: "watching"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ruby-on-rails, git, npm

I downloaded (git clone) 2 git repo, one of which is a React project, I successfully executed the command `npm run start-reactapp` , so that I can browse the website at localhost:3000.

I also need to start another Rails project, otherwise the back-end function (eg. member login) will be invalid. But the following error occurred when I executed `npm run watching` , which made me unable to proceed to the next rails server.

```
npm ERR! Missing script: "watching"
npm ERR!
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/keaton/.npm/_logs/2021-12-17T03_20_47_673Z-debug.log
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`npm run watching` means "run the command in `scripts.watching` in `package.json`". The error message means that you don't have a key `"watching"` inside the `"scripts"` object defined in `package.json`. So from wherever you are getting the instructions to run `npm run watching`, you need to find the entry that is supposed to be in your `package.json` and add it.

See the [`npm-run-script` docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-run-script) for more information about how `npm run` works.